# Timestamps in the Community Bulletin look out of place

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

First: Congrats on graduating! I love the new design (kudos to the designers) overall.

However, this has been bugging me:

[image]

Notice how 'tomorrow' is *ever so slightly* smaller than 'ends'? It turns out that it's specified to 11 point font, while the 'ends' is in 12 pt font. Can we please do this?

[image]

Comment: It's smaller because tomorrow is so far away.

Comment: and there's something I just have to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed. It will be live after our next production build.